# Http requests don't hit my Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, controller, mapping

My **controllers** have been working for a long while, but since when I got back to my uni project modifying my service layers, my controllers **don't get hit by mapped requests**. It's not a problem that regards folders position, since they're well positioned and previously everything worked.

Here a snippet of one target controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/notification")
public class NotificationController {

    @Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService;

    @GetMapping("/confirm/{tokenId}")
    public String confirm(@PathVariable String tokenId) {
        System.out.println("entering controller"); // da eliminare
        if(notificationService.confirm(tokenId))
            return "redirect:/notification/confirmation/success";
        else return "redirect:/notification/confirmation/failure";
    }
```

The sout line "entering controller" is never printed out when I try to access my controller and a 403 Whitelabel Error Page is shown. This is the log at the boot:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-10-29 11:29:04.075  INFO 15152 --- [           main] it.polito.ai.lab2.Lab2Application        : Starting Lab2Application on daniele-Inspiron-5548 with PID 15152 (/home/daniele/IdeaProjects/applicazioni-internet/target/classes started by daniele in /home/daniele/IdeaProjects/applicazioni-internet)
2020-10-29 11:29:04.087  INFO 15152 --- [           main] it.polito.ai.lab2.Lab2Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-29 11:29:05.318  INFO 15152 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-10-29 11:29:05.422  INFO 15152 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 95ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-10-29 11:29:05.789  INFO 15152 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-29 11:29:05.793  INFO 15152 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-29 11:29:05.795  INFO 15152 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@736309a9' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-29 11:29:05.797  INFO 15152 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-29 11:29:05.800  INFO 15152 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-10-29 11:29:06.025  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-10-29 11:29:06.033  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-29 11:29:06.034  INFO 15152 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-10-29 11:29:06.123  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-29 11:29:06.124  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1975 ms
2020-10-29 11:29:06.249  INFO 15152 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-29 11:29:06.350  INFO 15152 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-10-29 11:29:06.388  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-10-29 11:29:06.438  INFO 15152 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-10-29 11:29:06.560  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-10-29 11:29:06.709  INFO 15152 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2020-10-29 11:29:07.633  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-10-29 11:29:07.639  INFO 15152 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-29 11:29:07.674  WARN 15152 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-10-29 11:29:08.779  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-29 11:29:09.128  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@55c581e4, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2b9615cb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@19b0a9f2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@65b1693c, it.polito.ai.lab2.security.JwtTokenFilter@eaa07bb, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2eb03908, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1cc42abe, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6eae3730, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3f2169e9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1248f83, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@68dc2f53]
2020-10-29 11:29:09.188  INFO 15152 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-29 11:29:09.190  INFO 15152 --- [           main] it.polito.ai.lab2.Lab2Application        : Started Lab2Application in 5.8 seconds (JVM running for 6.722)
2020-10-29 11:30:18.794  INFO 15152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-29 11:30:18.799  INFO 15152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-29 11:30:18.816  INFO 15152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
2020-10-29 11:30:25.774  INFO 15152 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-29 11:30:25.780  INFO 15152 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-29 11:30:25.784  INFO 15152 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-29 11:30:25.802  INFO 15152 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Here the HTTP request:

```
http http://localhost:8080/notification/confirm/ae474af0-9d82-4cbb-b27b-f1446fc5c5a2
HTTP/1.1 403 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 10:52:48 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/notification/confirm/ae474af0-9d82-4cbb-b27b-f1446fc5c5a2",
    "status": 403,
    "timestamp": "2020-10-29T10:52:48.418+0000"
}
```

Previous documentation found online didn't help me. Thank you all.

Comment: Can you please add the GET request you are doing to hit that endpoint?

Comment: Did you check you Spring Web Security configuration. its seem you have to add path `/notification/*` there.

Comment: It looks like you have spring-security denying access to your endpoint, you are getting a 403.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression too, I don't get why it's denying me access to controllers and methods I haven't secured yet. Try to work on it in the while, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: You should configure Spring Security to ignore this mapping. 
If you didn't configure Spring Security at all then you should remove the dependency from maven/gradle, because Spring Security automatically blocks all routings.

Answer (score 0):

As burm87, Pandey Amit and Piotr Solarski said, it's a problem that regards Spring Security. I had to explicitly apply the permitAll() on those URLs and now everything it's ok again. Thank you all, your help has been precious.